# Jboss 6.1 Eclipse 4.19.0 Integration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jboss6.x, jboss-tools, hotdeploy

I have joined a new company where they do not allow us to download anything (Eclipse Marketplace). The default installation of eclipse does not have JBoss wildfly plugin.

Currently, even if I remove a comma in my code, it take 7 to 8 minutes to build/deploy/test

I need to configure Jboss in eclipse and able to do hot deployment whenever I change code. To download the plugin, I need to raise a request. Can I raise a request for below? would it solve my purpose? Can I install this plugin to my eclipse and configure jboss server in the server tab?

https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/2021-03/4.19.1.Final.html#update_site

Jboss 6.1 Eclipse 4.19.0 (I have eclipse 4.2 as well)

Any other idea would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you download the update site as a zip file, you will be able to install JBoss Tools plugins in your local Eclipse even in the case you don't have access to network